# Error when scanning barcode Mobile vision API?

Tags: java, android, android-vision

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView txt;
    Bitmap myBitmap;
    Button btn;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt);
        ImageView myImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgview);
         myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                getApplicationContext().getResources(),
                R.drawable.barcode);
        myImageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
         btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                bar();
            }
        });

    }

    public void bar(){
        BarcodeDetector detector =
                new BarcodeDetector.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                        .setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.DATA_MATRIX | Barcode.QR_CODE)
                        .build();
        if(!detector.isOperational()){
            txt.setText("Could not set up the detector!");
            return;
        }
        Frame frame = new Frame.Builder().setBitmap(myBitmap).build();
        SparseArray<Barcode> barcodes = detector.detect(frame);
        Barcode thisCode = barcodes.valueAt(0);
        txt.setText(thisCode.rawValue);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), thisCode.rawValue.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```

The `barcode.png` is: 
[food barcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEQLw.png)

Whenever I run the app using this as the Bitmap it crashes giving the `out of bounds array 0` exception. I am not sure why this is happening but the app keeps on crashing.

It can detect the square bar codes, but it cannot detect this one. What is the issue here?

**LOGCAT:** [Logcat from app](http://docdro.id/aN1QhsY)

Comment: can you please post logcat ?

Comment: @prasad, I have added the logcat

Comment: Please post it in the Question, not as a link to some off-site document sharing site.  And NOT as a "pdf" file, for crying out loud!

Answer (score 0):

The barcodes array is a `SparseArray`, that means that there could be gaps in the returned values, it could also be empty.

You should iterate over the keys and then retrieve the values from the `SparseArray` like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < barcodes.size(); i++) {
    Barcode barcode = barcodes.get(barcodes.keyAt(i));
    String value = barcode.displayValue;
}
```